# Nexus 3 default trust store location

Tags: java, nexus, nexus3, truststore

I'm a bit embarrassed to admit this but I can't, for the life of me, find any information online as to where Nexus 3 default trust store is.

I was able to find the following from my Nexus installation:

```
$DATA_DIR/sonatype-work/nexus3/keystores/node/private.ks 
$DATA_DIR/sonatype-work/nexus3/keystores/node/trusted.ks
```

Is the `trusted.ks` the Nexus 3 default trust store?  Where would I be able to find the default password for it?

Thank you